# Moving a Cocos2d-x Android project around in the local file system

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I've used `create-android-project.sh` to successfully create an Android app as part of my Cocos2d-x project. Now I want to move the app's directory and all contents to a different location in my local file system.

When I try to build the app after moving it I receive the error:

```
'make: *** Android NDK: Aborting.  Stop.'
```

**How can move my current project around the local file system and still have it build and run correctly?**

If I need to re-create the Android project after modifying the creation scripts that's fine too. I looked through `create-android-project.sh` and it wasn't obvious to me how I can modify the script to create the project in another directory of my choice. Or perhaps I need to adjust some of the settings in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `COCOS2DX_ROOT` in `build_native.sh` to an absolute path makes the project compile successfully.

This is similar to `NDK_ROOT` defined at the top of the file.